# Set java.security.policy property to a cross-platform file path

Tags: java

I'm trying to set the system property "java.security.policy" programmatically.

It works, as long as the path to the security policy file has no spaces.

```
File myFileReference = new File("C:\folder_name\security.policy")
System.setProperty("java.security.policy", myFileReference.getAbsolutePath());
System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());
```

If there are spaces int the file path, they get escaped with a %20, like this
"C:\folder%20name\security.policy".

The code above executes fine, but then all security checks fail. I assume setProperty doesn't really find the file.

On Windows, writing the file name without that escaping for spaces works.

```
System.setProperty("java.security.policy", "C:\\some folder\\wideopen.policy");
```

So, **the problem seems to be that %20 space escaping**. I could replace it using a regex, but maybe that would make it work just on Windows, and fails somewhere else.
Also, I don't want to hard-code the file path like that.

I looked at the Java doc for a File function that returns a "System.setProperty" compatible path name that works on any platform. I also tried things like toURI().toString(), to no avail.

Is there an elegant way to get a working file path String from a File reference in 1 line of code?

EDIT:
This was simplified code, I construct the file like this

```
URL policyURL = Class.class.getResource("/sub local folder/wideopen.policy");
new File(policyURL.getFile())
```

I needed a relative path, so I used that little getResource trick, which happens to return an URL, with the nasty %20 escapings.
I can use an URLDecoder to strip them away now that I know what the problem is.
But is there a less error prone way?

Comment: `File.getAbsolutePath()` does _not_ add "%20" escapes...

Comment: Is it possible you're retrieving this file path from somewhere else and stuffing it into a `File`? `File.getAbsolutePath()` will not strip `%20`s if they are already part of the path.

Comment: Yes, this was simplified code, I construct the file like this

    URL policyURL = Class.class.getResource("C:\\some folder\\wideopen.policy");
    new File(policyURL.getFile())
Edit: how do I get to format code in this miniaturized editor?

Comment: Why do you start with a URL and then convert to a File?  that is why you are getting the "%20" added.

Comment: Because I need a relative path, so I use that little getResource trick, which happens to return an URL...  
Oh, I see, the example is still too dumbed down, here's a better one  
URL policyURL = Class.class.getResource("/sub local folder/wideopen.policy");  
Didn't know it could cause such a pain. Is there a better way?  
I think I'm gonna use an URLDecoder now that I know.  
BTW double spaces to break line and 4 spaces to format code don't work in this mini-editor o_O

Comment: *"the example is still too dumbed down,"*  1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  2) Copy/paste these things.  3) New code goes in an edit to the question, not comments.

Comment: @DuncanJones
I solved using URLDecoder, not the prettiest thing, but did the trick.
How can I thank you and select an answer?

Comment: @user1600770 I appreciate your interest in thanking people (not sure if my comment was indeed correct). It would be best if you answer your own question and explain how you solved it. After two days, you can mark your own answer as accepted. Then everyone can see the issue is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved using the URLDecoder class. Here is a complete example of what I was trying to do, and the solution that made it work.

```
//here is the trick
URL policyFileURL = Class.class.getResource("/server/model/easy.policy");
String policyFilePath = "";
try {
    policyFilePath = URLDecoder.decode(policyFileURL.getFile(), "UTF-8");
}
catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {}

//here what I wanted to do (now it works)
server.activate(port, new File(policyFilePath));
```